How to mock a function which is not part of a class in Pytest?
I have a dependency in my target code called target/dep.py which should return "PATCHED" when I mock in the Pytest function. But after research, I can't seem to find how to patch a stand alone function in target/dep.py.
The answers I've seen say to use MagicMock() but that won't replace the intermediary use of the some_dep() function when called by the MyClass() instance.
target/myclass.py
from target.dep import some_dep

class MyClass:
    def do(self):
        return "thing done" + " " + some_dep()

target/dep.py
def some_dep():
    return "SOME DEP VALUE"

tests/test_thing.py
import mock

from target.dep import some_dep
from target.myclass import MyClass

@mock.patch("target.dep.some_dep", return_value="PATCHED", autospec=True)
def test_do(mock_some_dep):
    m = MyClass()
    assert m.do() == "thing done PATCHED"


Try patching "target.myclass.some_dep" instead of "target.dep.some_dep".  You want to patch the name in the myclass module, not in the dep module it's imported from.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Thank you @Samwise, that was it! I've heard the phrase "test where it's used not where it's defined" but never knew what that meant. Today I learned.

The other way to do this, of course, is just to pass the function into your class as a constructor parameter. That way, in your tests, you can pass in the fake version.

@Samwise I can make your answer the chosen one if you move to answer
